# No of strings of 'N' letters that can be formed using 'k' symbols

Tags: combinatorics

No of strings of 'N' letters that can be formed using 'k' symbols(they can be repeated). 2 of the given k symbols must always be present.

e.g for N=2 and k=2
Let Symbols be 'a','b' of which 'a' and 'b' should always be present
ans = 2

1. (a,b)
2. (b,a)

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem, apart from the verbatim problem text?

Comment: the 2 given symbols would serve as partition points after which i calculate further but this would lead to repetition  of answers.

Answer (score 3):

Say the two symbols that need to be included are named $a$ and $b$. The total number of words, ignoring the "$a$ and $b$ must be included", is $k^N$. Of them, $(k-1)^N$ does not include $b$, and $(k-1)^N$ does not include $a$, and as they are the invalid words, we subtract them from the total.

But now we've subtracted the words which contain neither $a$ nor $b$ twice, so we need to "un-subtract", that is to say add, them back once. There are $(k-2)^N$ such words.

In total:
$$
k^N - 2(k-1)^N + (k-2)^N
$$
words are valid.

Comment: +1,This is an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle, where we find the size of the intersection of the sets "strings that contain $a$" and "strings that contain $b$". It might be instructive to explain the general principle which can be used to solve many combinatorial problems.

Comment: @JiK Yes. But I've always been reluctant to put a name on it, because to struggling students, naming something usually means they stop thinking about what it _actually_ is, which will again make it more difficult for them to spot when it should be applied at another time. At least that's my experience with teaching high school probability and combinatorics. Of course, pointing out the overcounting, uncounting (and recounting for deeper levels) the first times the students meet it is a different story.

Comment: I was thinking about teaching men to fish, but now that I think of it, I believe you are right that too general concepts are confusing and actually hide the simple ideas behind them. Nevertheless, I think the answer could be improved by mentioning (after the answer to this specific question) that there is a general principle which can be used.

Comment: @JiK Maybe I should, but I am not able to at the moment, because my browser crashes the math.SE tab if I write too much because of all the real-time mathJaX rendering. It usually isn't a problem when writing fresh answers, because of the auto-saving feature, but editing is more or less out of the question, apart from single typos or the like.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. First compute the number of words of length $N$ on a $k$-letter alphabet $A$.
Then you have to exclude the words of length $N$ which do not contain at least two letters.
These words are of the form $a^N$ with $a \in A$...

Comment: the 2 letters that has 2 be excluded is fixed. If N=5 and my k(say 4)letters are 'a' to'd'then my answers should always include 'a' and 'b'.

So what you are saying is : 
total answers = 4^5
Now the second part should also ignore cases like ccddc,ccccc.

Comment: @user99766 It was not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways of filling n spaces using k symbols = k^n ...................(1)

Number of ways of forming the string excluding atleast one of the cumpulsory symbols = 2.(k-1)^n - (k-2)^n ..................(2)

hence, required number of ways is (1)-(2), which is **k^n - [2.(k-1)^n - (k-2)^n]**.

Comment: This counts some arrangements twice. E.g. when $N=3$, $k=2$, the string $aba$ can be obtained in two ways using your method.

Comment: your're right. when k=2, the no. of ways is just 2^n - 2.

Comment: but when k > 2, i think my method works.

Comment: If $k=3$, the string $aba$ can be also obtained in two ways: (1) add $a$ and $b$ in positions 1 and 2, respectively, and in the second phase add the third symbol; or (2) add $a$ and $b$ in positions 3 and 2, respectively, and in the second phase add the first symbol.

Comment: okay, i realize the mistake. i'll fix it.